# How to get sizes of screen elements dynamically in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, screen, frame

Sorry if my question is rather stupid: I am currently working on screen elements and need to get their sizes dynamically, depending on the size of the parent view.

If I use frames I need to get fixed sizes, right? For example:

```
let object = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20 + ( (10+34)*nrX ), 
  y: 10+(10+34)*nrY, width: 34, height: 34))
```

Of course, I can tune the sizes manually, but they remain fixed.

Is there any possibility to get the size of the elements and the distances between them dynamically? For example: Could each element have a size of 1/10 of the length of the parent view and 1/10 of the width?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

let testSubView = UIView()
var allObjects = [UIView]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    createTestSubview()

    testLabel.text = "Elements: \(allObjects.count)"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func createTestSubview(){


        // Creating testSubView

        testSubView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple //For test purpose

        testSubView.layer.borderWidth = 0

        testSubView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        testSubView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        testSubView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //Don't forget this line
        view.addSubview(testSubView)



        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testSubView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testSubView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)

        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testSubView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 0.7, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testSubView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, multiplier: 0.7, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

    createScreen()

}


func createObject(nrX:Int,nrY:Int,tagNr:Int) {



    let object = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10 + ( (10+20)*nrX ), y: 10+(10+20)*nrY, width: 20, height: 20))
    object.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow //For test purpose

    object.tag = tagNr

    object.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    testSubView.addSubview(object)
    allObjects.append(object)

}

func createScreen(){

    var count = 0
    let colum = 7

    let rows  = 7
    for j in 0..<rows{
        for i in 0..<colum{
            if count < 49 {
                createObject(nrX: i,nrY:j,tagNr:count)
                count += 1
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please use Autolayout it  is made for such things

Comment: also, don't call your variables like that - 'object' in createObject probably should be 'view'

Comment: Try this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: I know how the autolayout works, thank you. But the connection between using autolayout and having dynamically sizes of the screen elements within a subview is not obvious for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can get size of main view by:

```
let mainViewHeight = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height
let mainViewWidth = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.width
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but can I also use it for the subview? Or only for the main view?